# How can we read from a Minio cluster and write to another Minio cluster in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, minio, apache-spark-connector

I have an use case where we have some input data in a Minio cluster and we need to read and transform that data and then add them to another Minio cluster, and we have to do it using Spark. How can we achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [hadoop-aws](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html), you can simply read from and write to Minio using the s3a:// protocol. You should be able to set different different endpoints, credentials, etc. for each individual bucket, using the properties:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.endpoint
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.aws.credentials.provider
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.access.key
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.secret.key
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.path.style.access
```

So, imagine you have a Minio server https://minio1.com with bucket `dataIn` and https://minio2.com with bucket `dataOut`, you can set the following configuration (e.g. in `spark-defaults.conf`, using the `--conf` argument of `spark-submit`, or directly on your `SparkConf` object in code):

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.endpoint                  https://minio1.com
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.aws.credentials.provider  org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.access.key                ACCESS_KEY_1
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.secret.key                SECRET_KEY_1
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.path.style.access         true

spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataOut.endpoint                  https://minio2.com
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataOut.aws.credentials.provider  org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataOut.access.key                ACCESS_KEY_2
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataOut.secret.key                SECRET_KEY_2
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataOut.path.style.access         true
```

Then, in your application, simply transfer the data as follows:

```scala
val documents = spark.read.parquet("s3a://dataIn/path/to/data")

val transformed = documents.select(...) // do your transformations here

transformed.write.parquet("s3a://dataOut/path/to/target")
```

Comment: spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.access.secret should be spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.dataIn.secret.key

Comment: @NipunTalukdar whoops, you're right. I've edited the answer to use the *.secret.key properties.